# Using bootstrap, wrapping input text element in label causes input text to bold and not take up full width

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to wrap my text input with a label. I have some pickers on my form, and wrapping them in a label enables me to click on the label and activate the picker. However, when I try this with the text box it breaks the form. If I choose not to wrap the text boxes, the spacing between the label and the text box is different than the wrapped elements.

This doesn't work:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Title:
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: title" />
    </label>
</div>
```

This works:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Date:
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" data-provide="datepicker" data-bind="value  :date" id="Date" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Also, the text inside the text inputs should not be bold.

[image: form]

Comment: I think I missed the question..

Comment: You do not want bold text? And you posted a code that works..? What in the working code do you want to change exactly?

Comment: I don't want bold text in the input fields, and I want them to take up the full width in the form, like the other fields. I want to do this all with bootstrap, no CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You want to update your css, changing your label's to either display as block, or set their width to 100%. Then you also want to have input's inside labels set to a font-weight of normal.

```
label {
    display:block;
}
label input {
    font-weight:normal
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/95ygubwx/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, don't need to wrap elements for activation, you can just use the [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)  attribute:

```
<label for="title">Title</label>
<input id="title" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: title" />
```

If you don't want this, then you need to understand cascading styles.

Comment: We are strictly forbidden from using IDs on elements, to avoid collisions.

Comment: Then in Chrome use `Ctrl-Shift-I` to bring up dev tools and check out the applied styles to see what is being inherited.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap input inside label. **for** attribute of **label** element is doing the same thing you want to achieve.The correct way to create form control in bootstrap [is](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_input&stacked=h):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: title" id="title" />      
</div>
```

**Why input not taking full-width and text being bold**: Following is the label css applied by bootstrap library.

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

In your case, if you wrap input inside label, input is inhering the **font-weight: 700 px;** from it's parent(label) and hence bold.

And the parent label's **max-width: 100%** is restricting the input width. If it could have **width: 100%** than, input would take full width. There is difference between max-width and width.

Comment: max-width is not restricting the input width, display:inline-block is the reason why the input is not displaying at 100% width of it's parent.